# Error tras detener e iniciar mi instancia ec2 en AWS

Tags: aws, ec2

Detuve e inicié mi instancia ec2 que contiene la base de datos y la aplicación web, y ahora no puedo acceder a ella, ¿cómo puedo saber cuál es el problema?

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Has intentado revisar los logs en la instancia? Has entrado por consola / terminal a revisar si los servicios se despliegan en tiempo de arranque? Con ver un 404 en el navegador nos queda bien difícil ayudarte

Comment: hola amig@ bienvenid@ a stackoverflow te recomiendo que te leas este articulo: https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask Saludos.

Answer (score 0):

Entendería que tu web debe estar desplegado en algún servicio web (apache, nginx, etc). Lo que posiblemente ha ocurrido es que este servicio web se apagó cuando apagaste tu instancia ec2 y lo que debes hacer ahora es ejecutarlo nuevamente, pero para esto necesitas saber cuál es el servicio y también te recomendaría configurar el servidor para que levante el servicio web al prender.